# How to Use ML Kit Text detection for Non-Latin Asian (Bengali/hindi) LAnguages

Tags: android, ocr, firebase-mlkit, text-recognition

I have a visiting card contains Name and Adress. those are written in two different languages ( Bengali and English). Using MLKIt I am able to extract English Language Only. Now I want to extract the Bengali text from the captured image of the visiting card using android.

Answer (score 2):

ML Kit cloud-based text recognition supports these two languages:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/recognize-text

The supported languages in the cloud-based language is listed here:
https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages